# Cheesecake without eggs

Tags: cheesecake

Can a delicious cheesecake be made without eggs? Without aquafava or seeds? Eggs are becoming more and more expensive but I'd rather not give up cheesecake, if I can help it.

Comment: Most ‘no-bake cheesecake’ recipes don’t require eggs.  (Hopefully all, unless they’re using pasteurized eggs)

Comment: @Joe, or if you're somewhere that has essentially eliminated salmonella in eggs, like much of Europe

Comment: @ChrisH: except raw eggs don't provide much of anything useful to a cheesecake. In other words, the reason a no-bake cheesecake doesn't include eggs is the same reason it doesn't include frozen peas or a can of sardines.

Comment: @Marti, possibly true, though I could imagine some sort of cheesecake/mousse hybrid working quite nicely, unlike your other examples

Comment: I'm sorry. I should have included; I'm not looking for a no-bake cheesecake. Forgive me for not being more sure about my question. I'm definitely looking to cook/bake/steam my cheesecake but looking for something that omits eggs, aquafava or swelled seeds. Thank you.

Comment: A Hungarian proverb comes to mind, "if it's a goose, it should be a fat one": if you're going to splurge on something, might as well go all-out. If you want to make a cheesecake, make a proper cheesecake with eggs and sour cream and all the good stuff, and if eggs are expensive, maybe don't make it as often. (Or have oatmeal for breakfast instead of eggs.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that an eggless cheesecake is by definition going to be a no-bake cheesecake, because without the eggs or a substitute, heating cream cheese will just liquefy it.

Comment: I found an eggless recipe I'm willing to try. I'll update everyone with a link, IF it's worth the trouble. Thanks everyone. I've already got my 2 pounds of cream cheese.